# Continuity of $f'(x)$ if $f(x) =\begin{cases}e^{-\frac{1}{x}} & x>0 \\ 0 &\ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

The function $f:R \rightarrow R$ is defined as

> $$f(x) =\begin{cases}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}  &    x>0  \\ 
>  0 &\ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Discuss the continuity, differentiability of $f(x)$ and continuity of $f'(x)$

My approach:
$f(0^-)=f(0^+)=f(0)=0$  so it is continuous and also $f'(0^-)=f'(0^+)=0$

Now, $$f'(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x}}.\frac{1}{x^2}$$ so $f'(x)$ should not be continuous at $x=0$. However, I am not sure about the answer.

Comment: Note that $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}e^{-\frac1x}\cdot\frac1{x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x^2e^{-x}$.

Comment: So, f'(x) is continuous at x=0

Comment: @vikassharma In fact, it is not difficult to show that $f\in C^\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1{x^2}e^{-1/x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2e^{-x}\tag1
$$
For $x\gt0$, $e^x\gt\frac{x^3}6$, $e^{-x}\lt\frac6{x^3}$, so the limit above is $0$.

$(1)$ shows that the limit of the first derivative at $0$ from the right is $0$. The definition makes it clear that the derivative to the left of $0$ is $0$. Now we need to show that the derivative at $0$ is $0$
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{e^{-1/x}-0}{x-0}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac1xe^{-1/x}\tag2\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}xe^{-x}\tag3\\
&=0\tag4
\end{align}
$$
$(4)$ follows for the same reason as $(1)$.

Therefore, the first derivative is continuous at $0$.

---

**$\boldsymbol{f}$ is $\boldsymbol{C^\infty}$**

**Lemma $\bf{1}$:** for $x\gt0$,
$$
f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{P_n(x)}{x^{2n}}e^{-1/x}\tag5
$$
where $P_n(x)$ is a polynomial with degree at most $n$ and $P_n(0)=1$.

**Proof:**

Lemma $1$ is true for $n=0$ with $P_0(x)=1$. Suppose $(5)$ holds for some given $n$, then
$$
\begin{align}
f^{(n+1)}(x)
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f^{(n)}(x)\tag6\\
&=\frac{(1-2nx)P_n(x)+x^2P_n'(x)}{x^{2n+2}}e^{-1/x}\tag7
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $(5)$ holds for $n+1$ with $P_{n+1}(x)=(1-2nx)P_n(x)+x^2P_n'(x)$, which has degree at most $n+1$ and $P_{n+1}(0)=1$.

$\large\square$

Note that for $x\gt0$ and any $n\ge0$, $e^{1/x}\gt\frac1{(2n+1)!\,x^{2n+1}}$. Therefore,
$$
e^{-1/x}\le(2n+1)!\,x^{2n+1}\tag8
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^+}|f^{(n)}(x)|
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{|P_n(x)|}{x^{2n}}\,e^{-1/x}\tag9\\
&\le\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1{x^{2n}}(2n+1)!\,x^{2n+1}\tag{10}\\[6pt]
&=0\tag{11}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\phantom{1}(9)$: Lemma $1$
$(10)$: apply $(8)$
$(11)$: take it to the limit

$(11)$ and the Mean Value Theorem show that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$.

Thus, we have shown that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n\ge0$.

Comment: I think $\infty\cdot 0$ is undefined...Isn't it?

Comment: Please see the part where I said that $e^{-x}\lt\frac6{x^3}$ in the reason for $(1)$.

Comment: Hi Rob.   I hope that you're well and staying safe and healthy.  I was in the process of writing a proof of the generalization when I noticed you just edited your post to include such an expose.  So, (+1 ) for beating me to the punch.

Comment: @MarkViola: I am doing well. I hope you are as well. I don't think I've come across an analysis of this function on MSE (though, I've not searched), but as it is the basis for most of the $C_C^\infty$ functions I know, I felt it deserved some attention.

Comment: I believe that I posted an analogous solution for $e^{-1/x^2}$, but it was a while ago and I have not been as organized as you with respect to cataloguing my posted solutions.  I'll see if I can dig it up, but I suspect it'll be searching for a needle in a haystack.

Comment: Ah!  Rob I did find it [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3108964/show-that-e-1-x2-is-not-analytic-around-x-0/3109028#3109028).

Answer (score 0):

For the function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} e^{\frac{-1}{x}},& x>0\\ 0,& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

$x=0$ is a continuous function so is $e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$. So the only point of discontinuity of non-differentiability would be at $x=0$.
You can see that when $x$ is very close to $0$ but less than $0$, $f(x)=0$.
When $x>0$, use limits for when x is very close to zero but more than $0$ (i.e. $x=0^+$).
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{\frac{-1}{x}}=e^{\frac{-1}{0}}=e^{-\infty}$$
From the graph of $e^x$, you would not that $e^{-\infty}=0$.
 Thus, we can conclude that the function is **continuous for all values of $x$**.

But all continuous functions need not be differentiable. For a function to be differentiable the left-hand derivative (i.e $x=0^-$) and the right-hand derivative (RHD) (i.e $x=0^+$) must be the same. The left-hand derivative is obviously $0$ for $x=)^-$.RHD is also zero.

Therefore, the function $f(x)$ is **continous and differentiable at $x=0$**.